# Jetpack Compose ComposeView always return 0 width and height

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-view

So I'm trying to convert a composable to view with this approach

```
val composeView = ComposeView(LocalContext.current)
composeView.setContent { //My Composable }
```

But the problem is why when I get the `height` and `width` of that view directly, it's always return 0

```
Log.d("TAG", "height ${composeView.height} width ${composeView.width}")
```

But when I'm trying with this approach it gives a real value:

```
composeView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
    val height = composeView.height
    val width = composeView.width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ScreenSize {
@Composable
fun getScreenWidth(): Int {
    return LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp
}

@Composable
fun getScreenHeight(): Int {
    return LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp
}
}

Log.d("TAG", "height ${ScreenSize().getScreenHeight()} width ${ScreenSize().getScreenWidth()}")
```

and this is use of my example

```
Modifier.width(ScreenSize().getScreenWidth().dp / (length + 4))
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get the size of my screen but the size of a view of a composable